# How do I define client_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models `jobs` and `clients`.

A user can simple create a client and then assign them a number of jobs.

Here's my models for both.

job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
end
```

My form for creating a new job looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :job do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= <%= collection_select(:job, :client_ids, Client.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'None'}, { :multiple => true }) %>%>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

So as you can see there is a drop down box on the form which contains all of the clients.

When  try to save it however, I recieve this messed:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in JobsController#create

unknown attribute: client_id

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:22:in `new'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:22:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0ZVYpM9vTgY+BI55Y9yJDwCJwrwSgGL9xjHq8dz5OBE=",
 "job"=>{"name"=>"Sample Monthly",
 "client_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Save Job"}
```

My job controller is quite basic and looks like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @jobs = Job.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def new
    @jobs = Job.new 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def create
    @jobs = Job.new(params[:job])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @jobs.save
        format.html { redirect_to @jobs, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @jobs, status: :created, location: @jobs }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @jobs.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @jobs = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @jobs }
    end
  end
end
```

I have a junction table setup with both `job_id` and `client_id` as a integer value in them.
So I think its just a case of defining them in my controller under the new and create action like the error message suggests.

This is my first Rails app though sand im not quite sure how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be in your form. Try to replace this

```
<%= <%= collection_select(:job, :client_ids, Client.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'None'}, { :multiple => true }) %>%>
```

with

```
<%= f.association :clients %>
```

so the form will look like this

```
<%= simple_form_for @job do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :clients %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thankyou or the suggestion.

Now im getting `Association cannot be used in forms not associated with an object`

Comment: try replace `:job` with `@job` in your form

Comment: I had @job in there originally. But I had to use :job as I receive this error `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class `

Comment: do you have your form in jobs/new.html.erb? if no try this `Job.new` instead `:job`

Comment: i am not sure if it help but i have read something previously regarding this from here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html in 'Gotcha' section.

Comment: That worked!..sort of. Thanks!

The problem now is that im seeng the `job.name` but im not seeing other details like `job.client` after creation.

Comment: That will be some other problem maybe with attr_accessible if you are user rails 3.2